# infilepicker REST API Convert only converts first image

Tags: api, rest, image-conversion, filepicker.io

I want to show a collection of images in the form of thumbnails. I want these thumbnails to be converted on the fly, so what I am doing is setting the src of img to REST API call in a loop ie

```
<img src="https://www.filepicker.io/api/file/{FileHandle}/convert?w=200&h=230" />
```

FileHandle is changed in every iteration of loop, but for every call it gives me the first converted image.
Response status code for every subsequent call is 200.
I have paid plan.

Answer (score 0):

This is a caching issue with-in their system, hopefully they will look into it.
Source: InkFilePicker Support